# JQPlot - Show real input value in pointLabels label instead of point location

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, label, jqplot

How can I set pointLabels to show input value instead of point location ?

Now labels are like this :
[image]

mean labels are : 
16% 19% 
3% 7%
4% 11%
4% 7%

but I want to show like this :
16% 3%
3% 4%
4% 7%
4% 3%

mean each bar to show its own inputed percent value

Answer (score 0):

I have a few answers to a similar problems (or with samples related to your problem). They might be found below:

1. [Vertical stacked bar chart with sums on top.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10296988/613495)
2. [Horizontal stacked bar chart with links on bottom most bars.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10414510/613495)
3. [Vertical stacked bar chart with sums on top and with a custom tooltip.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10688315/613495)

Basically, **the approach I used**, since the plot options were not working, **was to set the point labels myself to appropriate values**.

This is a known issue, [reported here](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/402/stackedvalue-attribute-of-pointlabels-has), there seem to be some hacks but back then I tried the first recommended patch and it didn't help me. Yesterday someone posted another option maybe this one does work, though I didn't test it since I chose to stick to my solution, at least currently until it is fixed in the official release.