# JQPlot replot. Updating PointLabels

Tags: jqplot

I have a bar chart and I need to update its data, also a PointLabels. Data is updating, but PointLabels are the same, from previous plot. How to update a PointLabels?

```
// here are labels.

      var my_labels = [["2 g. <br /> 47$"],["2 g. <br /> 48$"],["7 g. <br /> 49$"],[],["10 g. <br /> 51$"],["6 g. <br /> 52$"],["4 g. <br /> 53$"]];
            $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
            var s1 = [2, 6, 7, '' , 10, 6, 4];
            var ticks = [47,48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53];
           // initializing plot  
            plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
                // Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..
                        canvasOverlay: {
                show: true,
                objects: [
                    {verticalLine: {
                        name: 'barney',
                        x: 4,
                        lineWidth: 2,
                        color: 'gray',
                        shadow: false
                    }}
                ]
            },
                animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
                seriesDefaults:{
                    renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,

// setting labels to my own defined labels




    pointLabels: { show: true, labels : my_labels, escapeHTML: false },
                    color: '#E6D49F'
                },
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        ticks: ticks,
                        max: 100
                    }
                },
                highlighter: { show: false },

            });

            $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick', 
                function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
                    $('#info1').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
                }
            );
        });
    // reploting function call
    setInterval(function(){replot()},4000);
        var a = 1;
        var labels;
// reploting function
        function replot()
        {
        var data;

    switch(a)
    {
    case 1:
      data = [[1,4], [2,6], [3, 8],[4,0],[5, 9],[6, 7],[7, 3]];
      labels = [["4 g. <br /> 47$"],["6 g. <br /> 48$"],["8 g. <br /> 49$"],[],["9 g. <br /> 51$"],["7 g. <br /> 52$"],["3 g. <br /> 53$"]];
      break;
    case 2:
      data = [[1,3], [2,7], [3, 7],[4,0],[5, 8],[6, 6],[7, 4]];
      labels = [["3 g. <br /> 47$"],["6 g. <br /> 48$"],["8 g. <br /> 49$"],[],["9 g. <br /> 51$"],["7 g. <br /> 52$"],["3 g. <br /> 53$"]];
      break;
    case 3:
      data = [[1,5], [2,5], [3, 9],[4,0],[5, 10],[6, 8],[7, 2]];
      labels = [["5 g. <br /> 47$"],["6 g. <br /> 48$"],["8 g. <br /> 49$"],[],["9 g. <br /> 51$"],["7 g. <br /> 52$"],["3 g. <br /> 53$"]];
      break;
    }
//updating data
        plot1.series[0].data = data;
//trying to update pointlabels
        plot1.series[0].pointLabels.labels = labels;
        plot1.replot();
        if(a == 3)
        a = 0;
        a++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and thought that I am doing something wrong. But now seeing someone else with the same problem, it seems that the problem is with the plugin itself.

I found a workaround to this problem from one of the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046987/jqplot-individual-values-not-totals-in-stacked-chart#comment20605247_9054953) on my [own post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9046987/456135).

After replot try directly updating the divs containig the point labels like this.

```
for(i=0;i<labels.length;i++){
    $("#chart1").find('.jqplot-series-0.jqplot-point-'+i).html(''+labels[i]);
}
```

I hope someone will provide a better solutions someday instead of this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is an old thread but I have just experienced the same issue and added the following as the first line in the "$.jqplot.PointLabels.draw" function, which removes all previously added labels prior to re-drawing them:

$('.jqplot-point-label',plot.target).remove();

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34615007/2880616). Updating `plot1.series[0].plugins.pointLabels.labels` instead of `plot1.series[0].pointLabels.labels` did the trick for me.