# JQPlot - Stacked Horizontal Bar Chart - No Bars When Stacked

Tags: bar-chart, jqplot, stacked

Having a strange issue with jqplot. I've created a horizontal bar chart with 2 series and 5 labels; all populated with variables from a table.

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [
    [[SERIESA[0],TITLE[0]], [SERIESA[1],TITLE[1]], [SERIESA[2],TITLE[2]], [SERIESA[3],TITLE[3]], [SERIESA[4],TITLE[4]]], 
    [[SERIESB[0],TITLE[0]], [SERIESB[1],TITLE[1]], [SERIESB[2],TITLE[2]], [SERIESB[3],TITLE[3]], [SERIESB[4],TITLE[4]]]], {
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        // Show point labels to the right ('e'ast) of each bar.
        // edgeTolerance of -15 allows labels flow outside the grid
        // up to 15 pixels.  If they flow out more than that, they 
        // will be hidden.
        pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15 },
        // Rotate the bar shadow as if bar is lit from top right.
        shadow: false,
        // Here's where we tell the chart it is oriented horizontally.
        rendererOptions: {
            barDirection: 'horizontal'
        }
    },
    axes: {
        yaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
        }
    }
});
```

This renders a lovely horizontal bar chart. I would like for the two series to be stacked under each label, but when I add the line

```
stackSeries: true,
```

above my seriesDefaults my bars all vanish. Everything else (labels, ticks, etc) remains the same. Is there something in addition to the stackSeries option I need to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix my problem (not entirely, but sufficiently for my need). This issue only occurs when I use custom lables pulled from somewhere else; if I use generic "1,2,3,4,etc." the graph stacks properly and shows data. Ideally I would have custom lables, but I can just put a simple table beside the graph to act as the axis labels.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what might be the reason with your code, what you showed appears to be all right. Maybe something wrong with the way you set the data, but then again it wouldn't work at all.

[Check out my example it might help you out.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/gXqPh/10/)

Comment: Yes my data is setup in a very strange way (I'm doing this on MS SharePoint using a mixture of CAML, jquery and javascript) but, like you say, since it renders correctly without stacking I don't see how the data setup would suddenly become the problem when stacked! Then again SharePoint can throw up some weird errors for no apparent reason... Thanks for having a look anyway!

Comment: Karl can you in this case if you still have this problem post a sample of code that presents your problem here http://jsfiddle.net/  , so we can have a look at what other things might be there?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can have custom labels, by adding tickt, for example:

```
 xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                tickOptions: {
                    angle: -90
                },
                labelOptions: {
                    fontSize: '11pt',
                },
                ticks: ['tick 1', 'tick 2'],
            }
```